# How to plot incomplete data with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am doing some processing and I want to plot progress. I know my total number of runs, I calculate results on every 100th run and I want to generate a new plot every time. So, my code looks something like this

```
start = time.time()
speeds = []
for step in range(steps):
    do_my_stuff()
    if step % 100 == 0:
        speeds.append((step + 1) / (time.time() - start))
        x = np.arrange(steps)
        y = np.array(speeds)
        plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
```

And, of course, I get "x and y must have same first dimension" error. It seems like such a simple and common issue, but for some reason I cannot find a ready solution. I am probably not googling for the right thing. What am I missing?

Update #1: To make myself a bit more clear. I want to redraw the plot every 100 iterations of my process. I want the plot to reflect the currently accumulated speed points. I want it to scale from 0 to maximum steps and I want it to be empty where speeds were not calculated yet.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. The `x=`, `y=` and `plot` commands needs to be outside the loop.

Comment: No, they do not. I want to redraw the plot every 100 iterations.

Comment: Steps has all the full length while speeds is still being built inside the loop. Hence they do not match in length.

Comment: I know. That is exactly the problem I am having. I just updated the post to clarify.

Comment: Try x = np.arrange(len(speeds))

Comment: That will make x too short. I want the x axis scale all the way to max steps, but I only want to plot the speeds I already calculated.

Comment: Try `x = np.arrange(len(speeds))` and `plt.xlim(xmax=steps)`

Comment: @Stelios xlim() seems to work, thank you. Now I am having a different problem, the plot treats each datapoint as a single step where in fact they are 100 steps apart. Any advice for that?

Comment: `x = np.arrange(len(speeds)) * 100` ?

Comment: Not quite, but `x = np.arange(100, 100 * (len(speeds) + 1), 100)` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would plot every single pair of x and y interactively, and set the limits of the plot to the desired values. You can still append the data if you need it later on. Look at this example:

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(5,5))
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
steps = 1000
ax.set_xlim(0,steps)
ax.plot(1,1)
plt.draw()

start = time.time()
speeds = []
for step in range(steps):
    #Your stuff here
    if step % 100 == 0:
        speed = (step + 1.0) / (time.time() - start)
        plt.plot(step, speed, 'ko')
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(1)
```